# How do I use cloudflare with amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I know that there are a few guides on the subject but I still can't make it work. I have a bucket, named let's say `images.mysite.com` and I've added a `cname` record to the cloudflare DNS settings like this:

```
type: CNAME
name: images
value: images.mysite.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

now if I add a picture to the bucket, let's say `mypicture.jpg`

I should be able to receive it with the following url:

```
http://images.mysite.com/mypicture.jpg
```

but it just returns 404, even though there is a `CF-Cache-Status:HIT` in the response headers

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to follow the instructions for creating a new AWS user and adding a policy to the bucket from [here](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/) and change `CNAME` value to `images.mysite.com.s3.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Neither of these things seems like it should have had any bearing on the issue described in the question.  Assuming you were using the correct regional web site endpoint, it doesn't make a lot of sense that you'd need to change your cname to the generic rest endpoint.  And bucket policy changes would not turn a 404 into a 200.  Incorrect bucket policy would have given you a 403.